# How to upload files larger than 2 GB to OSS of Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to upload some models (2.5 GB) to the Autodesk Forge Data Management API. I tried it buy postman and with resumable endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName/resumable

I get 504 timeout error.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you uploaded the whole file by the resumable endpoint directly?

resumable uploading means you need to split the file(file stream)  to chunks, and upload chunks one by one by the  resumable endpoint. I do not think Postman is a good tool to work with chunks. you may find some blogs about it in specific languages:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/nailing-large-files-uploads-forge-resumable-api

If you simply want to test file without much coding, I would recommend with the utility: Autodesk Forge Extension of VSCode. It has implemented resumable uploading.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petrbroz.vscode-forge-tools